# Full Text Search Fastify with Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search, mongoose-schema, fastify

Im trying to get a Full Text Search working through Fastify and Mongoose. But it returns an empty array.

There is no info online about this, so I just played with it for a while.
in db.ts I set the:

```
useCreateIndex: true
```

The Model (Benefit.ts):

```
export class Benefit extends BaseModel {
    _id: ObjectID;

    @prop({required: true, unique: true, index: true, text: true}) <-- set index & text to true
    name: string;

    @prop({index: true, text: true})
    details: string;

    const BenefitModel = getModelForClass(Benefit);
    BenefitModel.createIndexes(err => console.log('ERROR', err)); <-- this is what I tried // err=null
    export default BenefitModel;
```

The actual search (Benefit.controller.ts):

```
const searchResults = await benefitService.find(
     {$text: {$search: textSearch}}, <-- textSearch is valid and comes as a string
     {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}},
     );
```

the return is with status 200:

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "results": []
}
```

I think I dont set the index correctly?
Any help will be greatly appriciated.
And also will live long, **because there is no info about it anywhere**.

Thanks.

EDIT:
current route setup

```
export class BenefitController {
    protected routes: fastify.RouteOptions[];

constructor() {
        this.routes = [];
        this.setupRoutes();
    }

public getRoutes(): fastify.RouteOptions[] {
     return this.routes;
    }

protected setupRoutes(): void {
        this.routes.push({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/searchBenefit',
            handler: this.searchBenefit,
        });
}
new BenefitController().getRoutes().forEach((route: fastify.RouteOptions) => {
        fastify.route(route);
    });
```

**BTW I did set the indexes properly cause when I do listIndexes()
I get:**

```
{ v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: '_id_', ns: 'some-address.db.benefits' },
  {
    v: 2,
    unique: true,
    key: { name: 1 },
    name: 'name_1',
    ns: 'some-address.db.benefits',
    background: true
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { details: 1 },
    name: 'details_1',
    ns: 'some-address.db.benefits',
    background: true
  },
  {
    v: 2,
    key: { _fts: 'text', _ftsx: 1 },
    name: 'details_text',
    ns: 'some-address.db.benefits',
    background: true,
    weights: { details: 1 },
    default_language: 'english',
    language_override: 'language',
    textIndexVersion: 3
  }
```

Comment: did you add some json schema to the endpoint?

Comment: What do you mean?
can you give an example?

Comment: `fastify.get('/', {schema { response: { '2xx': {...} } } }, handler)`

Comment: I updated my question if you can see (in the EDIT)